# How can I get an array value and set it inside my inner html?

Tags: javascript, html

For my site I want to have a search page. If people search within this search bar they will go to another page and there will be a search query at the end of the url. This could be something like this: ?search=catan.

To prevent my site from showing all my 1600+ products, I added a pagination to my site and have the HTML elements inside an array. This is something like this:

```
var objJson = [
{ productName: '<div class="boardgame" data-category=" all Family   "><li><a href="/zooloretto-het-dobbelspel"><img src="img/zooloretto-het-dobbelspel.jpg" alt="Zooloretto: Het Dobbelspel"></a><h3>Zooloretto: Het Dobbelspel</h3><a href="/zooloretto-het-dobbelspel" class="productbutton">Meer info</a></li></div>'}
];
```

Within the code I am able to get the search result and to get all the different objects inside the array that match the search result.

The problem I have is when I want to show this in the designated HTML space inside my site, I cannot get the products inside this HTML. What am I doing wrong?

Javascript

```
var url, filter, search;
url = window.location.href.split("search=")[1];
search = url.split("+")[0];
filter = search.toLowerCase();
var items = objJson.filter(item => item.productName.indexOf(filter) !== -1)
console.log(items)
var listing_table = document.getElementById("products");
listing_table.innerHTML = "";

for (var i = 0; i < filter.length; i++) {
    listing_table.innerHTML += objJson[i].productName;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="productdiv" id="productsUl">
            <ul class="products" id="products">
    
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Well seems like you are missing adding a `<li>` element

Comment: Yeah, putting a `div` as a direct child to a `ul` is not semantic HTML and can cause weird stuff to happen.

Comment: Okay, if I use the same inside another script the products are showing fine. I suspect there is a problem with my for loop but can't seem to figure out how to show it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use UrlSearchParams to get url parameters

```
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const search= urlParams.get('search');
```

Why do you iterate your array as number of filter size?

```
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    listing_table.innerHTML += items[i].productName;
}
```

But In my opinion you shouldn't store html code in arrays. It is not efficient to store htmls in array and search your query in whole html code. I think it is enough to store only product informations (like product name, image url etc.) in array and search your query in this array. After filtering, you can create html code for each element of array and show it in browser like below.

```
let objects = [{
    productName:"Zooloretto: Het Dobbelspel",
    url:"/zooloretto-het-dobbelspel",
    imgUrl:"img/zooloretto-het-dobbelspel.jpg"
    }]
```

And create htmls for json objects.

```
let products = document.getElementById("products");

objects.map(obj=>{
    let objectHtml = `<li>
                        <a href="${obj.url}">
                            <img src="${obj.imgUrl}"/>
                        </a>
                        <h3>${obj.productName}</h3>
                      </li>`
    products.innerHTML+=objectHtml;

    }
)
```

Comment: This seems like a better way to approach this indeed. Is it wise to append this to the HTML by javascript or another method?

Comment: I edited answer to give detail about what I mean

Comment: Thanks man, will use this instead of my code.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to loop over `items`?

```
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    listing_table.innerHTML += items[i].productName;
}
```